# How to auto update database of Ms Access to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have a database in MS Access and I want it to be auto updated to MySQL database on host. Right now I can manually update the database only the first time by linking it through DNS, but I could not find any procedure to auto update it every time there are new rows in the database . Is this feature available or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can link your tables to MySQL and write directly in your "Access-Front-End" on them. Here is a Tutorial for linking tables to MySQL; a little bit old, but should still be valid:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables.html

Then, you can change the source tables in your queries to the linked mySQL tables. If you want to use the access tables and synchronize with
 mySQL, you have to think about a synchronisation solution. e.g. (Data) Macro, VBA Code,...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to import? but before that I think your database must be must save as .sql file